# Problem setting a computed-column

Tags: sql-server, calculated-columns, string-length

I am trying to set this col but I get an error:

```
FirstName + (CASE WHEN LEN(FirstName + LastName) > 0 THEN ' ' ELSE '') + LastName
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should close CASE with END and also, to my opinion, the following value will be better:

```
FirstName + (CASE WHEN LEN(FirstName) > 0 AND LEN(LastName) > 0 THEN ' ' ELSE '' END) + LastName
```

Comment: Good point about counting the chars and sum them vs. concatenating strings which cost more performance.

Answer (score 1):

```
FirstName + (CASE WHEN LEN(FirstName + LastName) > 0 THEN ' ' ELSE '' end) + LastName
```

missing the end

Comment: But what if last name length was 0 ?

Comment: I was just addressing the OP's syntax problem, not his approach.